# Set unbound textbox value depending on other textbox value

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I have a report in Access 2016 with two columns (Name and Group) from a query.
I want to fill an unbound textbox in my report depending on the value in Group.

I get the last group value. I want it to look for each row value.

I tried to get the value from Group to display in textbox.

```
if me.group.value = "1" then me.textbox = "blablabla" end if
```

It only works if I use the last group.value ("4"), but every row will get "blablabla".

I tried _load and _open , _activate. Don't know the difference though.

Comment: Don't use VBA. Put expression in textbox ControlSource or do calc in query used as report RecordSource and bind textbox to that field. `IIf([Group] = 1, "blablabla", Null)`.

Comment: wow so simple, that saved me tons of work. So grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use VBA. Put expression in textbox ControlSource or do calc in query used as report RecordSource and bind textbox to that field.

`IIf([Group] = 1, "blablabla", Null)`